# Program terminated due to time out

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

PROBLEM :

You are given a list of size N, initialized with zeroes. You have to perform M operations on the list and output the maximum of final values of all the  elements in the list. For every operation, you are given three integers a,b  and k and you have to add value  to all the elements ranging from index a to b(both inclusive).

Input Format

First line will contain two integers N and M separated by a single space.
Next  lines will contain three integers a,b and k separated by a single space.
Numbers in list are numbered from 1 to N.

Here is the code which I have written:

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
arr=[]
for i in range(n+1):
   arr.append(0)
for j in range(m):
    a,b,k=map(int,input().split())
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        arr[i]+=k;

print(max(arr))
```

When I try to submit my solution I get a "TERMINATED DUE TO TIMOUT" message.Could you please suggest a strategy to avoid these kind of errors and also a solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the input values also ?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to take the input like that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop over the list range; instead, use `map` again to increment the indicated values.  Something like

```
for j in range(m):
    a,b,k=map(int,input().split())
    arr[a:b+1] = map(lambda <increment-by-k>, arr[a:b+1])
```

This should let your resident optimization swoop in and save some time.

Comment: At least in CPython, `map` with a `lambda` is basically always slower than an equivalent listcomp or genexpr that can inline the body of the `lambda` (avoiding per item function call overhead). And it almost never beats listcomp/genexpr unless the input is large, *and* the mapping function is a built-in implemented in C (and sometimes not even then). `arr[a:b+1] = map(k.__add__, arr[a:b+1])` _might_ be faster, but I'd usually go with `a[a:b+1] = [x+k for x in arr[a:b+1]]` for simplicity and readability. Batching the work is a savings, but `map`+`lambda` will undo some of that gain.

Comment: In Python 3.5.4, map seems to be somewhat faster than listcomp on a lambda.  However, I'd love to see another answer -- write that up for posterity?

Comment: I'm going to guess you messed up your benchmark; remember, `map` is lazy, so if you don't run out the result, it doesn't actually do any work. To test, I just used `ipython`'s `%timeit -r5` for `k = 2`, `arr = list(range(100))`, then tested three statements `list(map(lambda x: x+k, arr[10:60]))`, `[x+k for x in arr[10:60]]` and `list(map(k.__add__, arr[10:60]))`. Timings were 6.43 µs for `map`+`lambda`, 2.94 µs for listcomp, and 2.91 µs for `map`+C built-in function, which is pretty typical behavior in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an algorithm that has better complexity than O(M*N).

You can put interval delimiters in a list:

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
intervals = []
arr = [0 for i in range(n)]

for j in range(m):
    a,b,k=map(int,input().split())
    intervals += [(str(a), "begin", k)]
    intervals += [(str(b), "end", k)]
intervals = sorted(intervals, key=lambda x: x[0]+x[1])

k, i = 0, 0
for op in intervals:
    ind = int(op[0])
    if op[1] == "begin":
        while ind > i:
            arr[i] += k
            i += 1
        k += op[2]
    else:
        while i <= ind:
            arr[i] += k
            i+= 1
        k -= op[2]

print(arr)
```

If the sorting algorithm is O(MlogM), this is O(MlogM + N)